# On AWS X-Ray, stop tracing a particular path on a Node API running in a docker container on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

I have a Node API running inside a docker container on ECS. I am using X-Ray to trace incoming requests.

I would like to instruct x-ray to **not trace a particular API end-point** on my Node API. Is this possible?

The API endpoint is:

```
/api/upload/directUploadConfirmation
```

I do not want that end-point traced via X-Ray.

**What I have tried**

I tried to create a sampling rule via the X-Ray console. I wanted to cheat and see for this paritular URL, capture 0 requests per second. But that plan failed because it doesn't accept 0, the number has to be greater than or equal to 1.

[image: added image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The CloudWatch console team has since fixed this in production. Thanks for finding this issue!

=============================================================

Just to confirm, are you using [the X-Ray SDK for Node.JS](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node)? If you are, feel free to open an issue there so people familiar with the SDK can help answer your question too!

Otherwise, I was able to create a sampling rule with 0 `Reservoir Size` and 0 `Fixed Rate`. Below is a picture showing how to get to the X-Ray console to create this.

[image: X-Ray console for creating a sampling rule]

[The AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html#xray-console-sampling-options) lists several Sampling options that you can use *including* `URL Path`. This option is not available in APIGW, but should be available in ECS which you mentioned you are using. In my image I am using that to filter output requests to `URL Path` `/foo/bar`.

> But that plan failed because it doesn't accept 0, the number has to be greater than or equal to 1.

Can you please confirm where you saw it fail to accept 0? Based on that I can try to replicate your setup and see if I get the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: See updated question. I've added a screenshot showing the error I got.

Comment: Thanks for that update, it was super helpful! I've reached out to that team for help getting a fix because you should be able to create what you're describing. In the meantime, you should be able to access the X-Ray console I have to resolve your issue. I've updated my answer with a picture to show how I got there!

Comment: Thanks @NathanielRuiz, I went back to using the old UI and you're right, my value of `0` got accepted! Thanks very much.